# Limitar el espacio de almacenamiento por usuario

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy trabajando en un nuevo proyecto y me preguntaba si es posible **limitar el espacio de almacenamiento por usuario en Laravel**

Me explico, lo que busco es que si el usuario tiene el rol `student` entonces podrá almacenar hasta 1GB en su perfil.

Y si hay un usuario de tipo `teacher` tendrá espacio ilimitado u otro tipo de cantidad de espacio como 4GB... Y así sucesivamente. Llevo varias semanas investigando y probando pero aún no encuentro una solución que realmente me aporte a lo que estoy buscando.

Todas las sugerencias son bienvenidas. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo creando una carpeta para cada usuario:
y calculando el espacio utilizado si lo exede ya no le permites subir mas archivos;

```
<?php 


function formatBytes2($size, $precision = 0){
    $unit = ['Byte','KB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB'];

    for($i = 0; $size >= 1024 && $i < count($unit)-1; $i++){
        $size /= 1024;
    }
    return array(round($size, $precision),$unit[$i]);
}

function GetDirectorySize($path){
    $bytestotal = 0;
    $path = realpath($path);
    if($path!==false && $path!='' && file_exists($path)){
        foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS)) as $object){
            $bytestotal += $object->getSize();
        }
    }

    return formatBytes2($bytestotal);
}
//ejemplo a 100MB
$max_size= array(100,"MB");
$path = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$size = GetDirectorySize($path."jhon");
$total = round($max_size[0]-$size[0],2);

if ($size[0] >= $max_size[0] && $size[1] == $max_size[1]) {
    echo "as alcanzao del limite de espacio ya no puedes subir mas archivos";
}else{
    echo "actualmente tienes: {$size[0]} {$size[1]} en uso, restan: {$total} {$size[1]} de {$max_size[0]} {$size[1]}";
}
?>
```

Comment: Genial, gracias por la pronta respuesta. Voy a implementarlo para ver si me funciona a la perfección. Gracias por la orientación